# Javascript "Empty" function Validator

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I want to alert a user if a field is empty in Javascript using a function.... I already have one program set up I just need to add on this other 'empty' function....this is what I have so far...Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
var time = 0;

function printTime() {
  time = prompt("Please enter the time in 24 hour clock format eg 00:00 ");
  
  function isEmptyTime() {
    var time = time.split(":");
    var hours = parseInt(time[0]);
    var minutes = parseInt(time[1]);

    if (time == "00:00") {
      document.write("Midnight");
    } else if (time == "12:00") {
      document.write("Noon");
    } else if (hours < 12) {
      document.write("" + hours + ":" + minutes + " AM");
    } else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {
      hours = hours - 12;
      document.write("" + hours + ":" + minutes + " PM");
    } else(time.length == 0) {
      document.write("No data has been entered");
    }
  }
}

printTime();
```

Comment: You never call `isEmptyTime()`.

Comment: Need to do a checking on time before `time.split(":");`, such as `if(!time)document.write("No data has been entered");`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have a few items incorrect here.  First, you have an inner function that you never invoke.  I moved this function outside of `printTime()`.  Secondly, the last `else` block needs to be an `else if`.  Lastly, you were reusing the time variable multiple times in the `isEmptyTime()` method which re-purposed is meaning.

This should work for you:

```js
var time = "";

function isEmptyTime(time) 
{
  var t = time.split(":");
  var hours = parseInt(t[0]);
  var minutes = parseInt(t[1]);
  var result = "";
  
  if (time == "00:00")
  {
    result = "Midnight";
  } 
  else if (time == "12:00") 
  {
    result = "Noon";
  } 
  else if (hours < 12) 
  {
    result = "" + hours + ":" + minutes + " AM";
  }
  else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) 
  {
    hours = hours - 12;
    result = "" + hours + ":" + minutes + " PM";
  }
  else if (time.length == 0) 
  {
    result = "No data has been entered";
  }
  console.log(result);
}

function printTime() 
{
  time = prompt("Please enter the time in 24 hour clock format eg 00:00 ");
  isEmptyTime(time);
}

printTime();
```